# SSRS Date Aging Expression for 0-30 DAYS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-expression

I am working on an aging report BI Project and i  am getting stuck on these expressions. I am trying to Count the number of application in between  NOW() and the date field.  I am getting a count back but not the total number of application in the date range.

**0-30 DAYS**

```
=iif(DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value, now())>=0 and DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value,Now())<=30,1,0)
```

**31-60 DAYS**

```
=iif(DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value, now())>=31 and DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value,Now())<=60,1,0)
```

**61-90 DAYS**

```
=iif(DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value, now())>=61 and DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value,Now())<=90,1,0)
```

**>91 DAYS**

```
=iif(DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value, now())>=91 and DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value,Now())<=99999999,1,0)
```

Thanks,
Arron

Comment: It would be better to calculate it in your SQL query if you can.

Comment: Not sure what you mean you are getting a count but not the total number.   Do you maybe just need to put each of those expressions in a SUM() function?

Comment: Tab Alleman. That did work. The sum added the values i need to completed the statement.  I feel pretty LAME that is was that simple. Below is the correct resolution: `=SUM(IIF(DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value, now())>31 and DateDiff("d",Fields!APP_RECEVIED.Value,Now())<=60, 1, 0))`

Comment: "I am trying to Count the number of application in between NOW() and the date field." <- That sounds like you only need the `DateDiffs` on the right of the `and` in each expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use an execute SQL task to call a script that does these calculations for you.  Write the Script in SSMS, test it and make sure the data returns what you need, then put it into the task.  SQL is very good at this.